# Значение '101' недопустимо для 'Value'. 'Value' должно лежать в диапозоне от 'minimum' до 'maximum'. (Parameter 'value') Actual value was 101

Tags: c#, visual-studio, c#-6.0

Я пишу код на C# для программы, которая очищает временные файлы (кэш-файлы), в таких директориях как: C:\Users\Имя пользователя\AppData\Local\Temp и в C:\Windows\Temp. При отладки программы появляется следующая ошибка:

*Необрабатываемое исключение в приложении. При нажатии кнопки "Продолжить" приложение проигнорирует ошибку и попытается продолжить работу. При нажатии кнопки "Выход" приложение немедленно завершит работу.*

*Значение '101' недопустимо для 'Value'. 'Value' должно лежать в диапозоне от 'minimum' до 'maximum'. (Parameter 'value')
Actual value was 101.*

*Подробная информация об использовании оперативной
(JIT) отладки вместо данного диалогового
окна содержится в конце этого сообщения.*

************** Текст исключения **************

*System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Значение '101' недопустимо для 'Value'. 'Value' должно лежать в диапазоне от 'minimum' до 'maximum'. (Parameter 'value')
Actual value was 101.*

*at System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar.set_Value(Int32 value) -
at DebrisCleaner.Form1.ScanFolder(String folderPath, Int64& totalSize) in D:\Projects\DebrisCleaner\DebrisCleaner\Form1.cs:line 87*

*at DebrisCleaner.Form1.AnalyzeFolders() in D:\Projects\DebrisCleaner\DebrisCleaner\Form1.cs:line 64*

*at DebrisCleaner.Form1.<AnalyzeButton_Click>b__3_0() in D:\Projects\DebrisCleaner\DebrisCleaner\Form1.cs:line 29*

*at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<.cctor>b__272_0(Object obj)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(Thread threadPoolThread, ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)*

--- End of stack trace from previous location ---

*at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(Thread threadPoolThread, ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)*

--- End of stack trace from previous location ---

*at DebrisCleaner.Form1.AnalyzeButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\Projects\DebrisCleaner\DebrisCleaner\Form1.cs:line 29*

*at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.b__128_0(Object state)*

**Код C#:**

```
private void ScanFolder(string folderPath, ref long totalSize)
    {
        var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(folderPath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            .Where(file => !IsSystemFile(file));

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            try
            {
                totalSize += new FileInfo(file).Length;
                filesListBox.Items.Add(file);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                // Ошибка доступа к файлу
            }

            ProgressBar.Value++
        }
    }
```

Comment: Задайте свойство [ProgressBar.Maximum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.progressbar.maximum?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) равным количеству файлов в папке

Comment: Так можно замедлить обработку большого кол-ва объектов. Даже если в ProgressBar есть оптимизация.

Comment: Я исправил, на то что вы предложили, но: 1)https://imgur.com/0vcvFwz 2)https://imgur.com/poKv5vt 3)https://imgur.com/PgWCYHT

Comment: Извините за ошибки - поторопился. См. исправленный ответ. И пишите комментарии под моим ответом, иначе я не получу извещение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибку даёт "progressBar.Value++", когда "progressBar.Value"=100. Нужно как-то предварительно оценить количество обрабатываемых объектов и привести это к 100%, чтобы "progressBar.Value" находилось в диапазоне от 0 до 100%:

```
private void ScanFolder(string folderPath, ref long totalSize)
{
    var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(folderPath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        .Where(file => !IsSystemFile(file));

    if (files is null) return; // на всякий случай, не уверен, что не может быть null
    var fc = files.Count(); // получаем кол-во файлов
    if (fc==0) return;
    double ttl = 0, dv = 100 / (double)fc; // вводим счётчик и инкремент, приведённый к 100%
    int lttl = 0;

    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        try
        {
            totalSize += new FileInfo(file).Length;
            filesListBox.Items.Add(file);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // Ошибка доступа к файлу
        }

        ttl += dv; // увеличиваем счётчик
        if ((int)ttl > lttl) progressBar.Value = lttl = (int)ttl; // это снизит частоту обновления ProgressBar, если время критично или очень много файлов, особенно маленьких
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Что вы делаете с сэкономленными строками, ну, когда тело `if` пишете в той же строке, а не переносите на другую? )

Comment: @CrazyElf  я вижу сразу бОльшую часть кода без прокрутки экрана

Comment: Зато вы хуже видите его структуру )

Comment: @CrazyElf это кому как. Структура кода - не знаю, зачем ею любоваться. Структура объетов хорошо видна в обозревателе. Я предпочитаю уместить код в строку, если там выражено какое-то законченное действие. Ну, и на экран по ширине должно влезать. Это как предложения в естественном языке - их же никто не пишет по слову в строчке. В общем, каждый пришет, как ему нравится. Если есть другие критерии, например, аутсорсинг, групповая работа, то их, безусловно, нужно учитывать.

Comment: @CrazyElf "Вагонные споры – последнее дело, когда больше нечего пить, но поезд идет, бутыль опустела, и тянет поговорить." Что бы вы сказали, увидев такое "Зато вы хуже видите его структуру" положение в коде? Я могу сказать, что: 1) метод применён не к тому объекту --> "Я хуже вижу его структуру"; 2) не рассмотрены все случаи, сделано безосновательное обобщение, в других случаях структурирование может использоваться. Я вставил три команды if, и у всех трёх по одной команде после - нечего структурировать.